# How to get MAX(COUNT) in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get the name of the entity which has MAX count in the dataset and would also like to get the count of the same.

```
SELECT 
    STORE_TYPE AS 'FREQUENT CHANNEL', 
    COUNT(STORE_TYPE) AS 'TOTAL TRANSACTIONS'
FROM 
    TRANSACTION_INFO
GROUP BY 
    STORE_TYPE
```

This returns the count of the `STORE_TYPE` along with the `TOTAL_TRANSACTIONS`.

Now, I would like to **fetch** the `STORE_TYPE` along with `TOTAL TRANSACTIONS` which has performed the best (MAX).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I am using MSSQL server

Comment: . . If you are using SQL Server, you should look at the answer I posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want one row, the logic would be `group by` to calculate the count.  Then `order by` and some way of limiting the result to the top:

```
SELECT STORE_TYPE, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM TRANSACTION_INFO
GROUP BY STORE_TYPE
ORDER BY cnt DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

In the event of ties, this only returns one arbitrary row with the highest value.  The best way to handle ties depends on the database.

`FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` is the ISO/ANSI standard for limiting the result set to one row.  Your database may use a different syntax for this.

I also strongly discourage you from using single quotes for column aliases.  Use names that don't need to be escaped -- that is the best advise.  Otherwise, use the escape mechanism for your database, typically double quotes, backticks, or square braces.

EDIT:

The solution in SQL Server that includes ties is:

```
SELECT TOP (1) STORE_TYPE, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM TRANSACTION_INFO
GROUP BY STORE_TYPE
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

If you only want one row, remove the `WITH TIES`.

Comment: I was wondering how to handle ties :-) There is no elegant way, right?

Comment: @DavidBrossard . . . "Elegance" is subjective.  There are just a variety of different ways depending on the database.  The "official" way would use window functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply ORDER BY the max and then limit to a single row.

```
SELECT 
STORE_TYPE AS 'FREQUENT CHANNEL', 
COUNT(STORE_TYPE) AS 'TOTAL TRANSACTIONS'
FROM TRANSACTION_INFO
GROUP BY STORE_TYPE
ORDER BY 'TOTAL TRANSACTIONS' DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The way to LIMIT depends on the SQL dialect.

Comment: This gives the `min` I think.

Comment: No, why would you think so?

Comment: I'm not not the only one :) now I see that yogesh fixed by adding `desc`.

Comment: I see :-) I hadn't noticed the edit. Good catch, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers work well, as long as there's a single `store_type` that is doing best. If you also want to account for multiple ones tied in first place you should use:

```
with s (t, c) as (
  select store_type, count(*)
    from transaction_info group by store_type
)
select
    t as 'FREQUENT CHANNEL',
    c as 'TOTAL TRANSACTIONS'
  from s
  where c = (select max(c) from s)
```

This query will show you one or more rows.